# Return False being ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Any ideas why the "return false" in the below is being ignored and opening the URL pages in a new window? On click the external URL should be loaded into the content div.

My HTML:

```
<div id="maincontainer">
<div id="mainnav">
<a class="menuitem" id="home" href="#">Home</a>
<a class="menuitem" id="about" href="about.html">About</a>
<a class="menuitem" id="contact" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer">
<p><a class="menuitem" id="find" href="find.html">Find...</a></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My script:

```
$('#home a').click(function(){
$("#content").hide();
$("#slider1_container").fadeIn();
});

$('#about a').click(function() {
$("#slider1_container, #contact, #find").hide();
  var url=$(this).attr('href');
  $('#content').load(url);
  return false;
});

$('#contact a').click(function() {
$("#slider1_container, #about, #find").hide();
  var url=$(this).attr('href');
  $('#content').load(url);
  return false;
});

$('#find a').click(function() {
$("#slider1_container, #about, #contact").hide();
  var url=$(this).attr('href');
  $('#content').load(url);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: When faced with this kind of problem, the best thing you can do is open the debugger built into your browser. On most browsers it's F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I (or Cmd+Option+I on a Mac). Navigate to the sources pane, find your code, click in the margin to set a breakpoint, and then watch your code run. In this case, you'd find that the breakpoint in the `click` handler never got reached at all.

Answer (score 3):

Your `#home`, `#about`, and `#contact` elements don't have a *descendant* `a` element, so your selectors are incorrect and the event isn't being hooked at all. Change `$("#home a")` to simply `$("#home")` (and the same for `about`, `contact`).

---

Side note: You can also condense those last three `click` handlers, as they all do the same thing with the only difference being which element is not hidden:

```
$('#home a').click(function(){
  $("#content").hide();
  $("#slider1_container").fadeIn();
});

$("#about, #contact, #find").click(function() {
  $("#slider1_container, #about, #contact, #find").not(this).hide();
  var url=$(this).attr('href');
  $('#content').load(url);
  return false;
});
```

Note the use of `.not(this)` to avoid hiding the current element.

Comment: That did it! Thanks. I should've seen that.

Comment: @paulja: Glad that helped. I added a side note above, btw, you can combine three of those four `click` handlers. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`#about a`, etc. don't match anything. `#about a` would match something like:

```
<div id="about"><a href="example.html">this</a></div>
```

You want:

```
$('a#about')
```

or, really, just:

```
$('#about')
```

since IDs are unique.